# ¿Como enviar información de un useState(hook) a otra clase?

Tags: reactjs, clase, react-hooks, class

Tengo la siguiente clase que lista una serie de volcanes con código y nombre:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {useFetchVolcans} from '../assets/hooks/useFetchVolcans';
import Accordion from 'react-bootstrap/Accordion';

function Bar() {

//realizo una petición para pedir la lista de los volcanes y su codigos
const {data} = useFetchVolcans()

const [volcanInicio,setVolcanInicio] = useState()

//Aquí se modifica el código guardado si se elige uno u otro volcán de la lista 
const handleVolcanInicio = (e)=>{
        setVolcanInicio(e.target.value)
    }

  return(
  <div className="barLeft">
   //Aquí listo la información en un botón desplegable
    <Accordion>
      <Accordion.Item eventKey="0">
          <Accordion.Header>Volcanes</Accordion.Header>
              <Accordion.Body>
                  <select value={volcanInicio} onChange={handleVolcanInicio} class="form-select">
                              <option value="0">Elige un volcan</option>
                              {data.map((item) => (
                                <option value={item.code}>{item.name}</option>
                              ))}
                  </select>
             </Accordion.Body>
       </Accordion.Item>
    </Accordion>
  </div>
  );
}

export default Bar;
```

Lo que necesito es mandar la información del código guardado en setVolcanInicio a otra clase y que esto se realice cada vez que se elije un volcán de la lista.

Comment: Bar y el otro componente tienen algun componente padre en comun?

Comment: @LuisS.Romero si se consumen en una clase llamada PageHome (quería añadir el pero no se como en comentarios hacerlo no mefunciono los ``` jajaja)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el caso de tener un componente padre, podrías declarar el useState en el padre, y pasarlo por props, hacia abajo pasas por ejemplo volcanInicio y para arriba pasas setVolcanInicio, Ej:

Digamos que hay un componente padre PageHome, en algún lugar de este componente tendrás un:

```
return (
<div>
</div>
)
```

---

Entones digamos que tenemos 2 componentes más, Componente1 y Componente2, ahora PageHome se vería así.

```
//debes hacer al inicio el import de Componente1 y Componente2 con sus correspondientes rutas, muchas veces lo hace solo al agregarlos abajo.
return (
<div>
<Componente1 />
<Componente2 />
</div>
)
```

---

Por último pasaremos un valor del Componente2 al Componente1 pasando por PageHome, entonces en PageHome quedaría algo así:

```
import { useState } from "react";

function PageHome() {
  const [volcanInicio, setVolcanInicio] = useState("");
  return (
    <div>
      <Componente1 volcanInicio={volcanInicio} />
      <Componente2 setVolcanInicio={setVolcanInicio} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default PageHome;
```

---

En el Componente1 recibimos por props volcanInicio para mostrarlo, quedaría algo así:

```
import React from 'react'

function Componente1({volcanInicio}) {
    return (
        <div>
        <span>{volcanInicio}</span>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Componente1
```

---

Ahora en el Componente2 vamos a hacer que al ingresar algo en un input, se actualice el estado de volcanInicio, entonces el Componente2 quedaría así:

```
import React from 'react'

function Componente2({setVolcanInicio}) {
    return (
        <div>
        <input type="text" id='campoX' name="campoX" onChange={(e)=> setVolcanInicio(e.target.value)}>           
        </input>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Componente2
```

Con esto sería necesario, lo que estamos haciendo es usar el setVolcanInicio desde Componente2 y volcanInicio desde Componente1, aprovechando el pasaje por props, usando al padre(PageHome) como "intermediario"

Dado que un componente se actualiza cuando cambia su estado o sus props, al cambiar el estado volcanInicio, y este estar definido en PageHome, cada vez que se ingrese algo en el input de Componente2, se hará el render de PageHome, haciendo que se muestre el valor actualizado en Componente2.

En resumen al componente que hará el cambio le pasas por props el setVolcanInicio, este setter es una función, y al componente que mostrará el dato le pasas por props volcanInicio, este es el valor que mostrarás.

Comment: jajaja me enrede un poco con la explicaciones finales , pero ya un amigo me lo explico y si efectivamente funciona y puedo obtener la información que quería aun que aun me falta un parte (pero no se si postear otra pregunta aparte) es que yo quería que apenas le diera clic en la lista de volcanes que se mostraba en el `acordeón` este realizara la petición, pero  si no le coloco un botón para que haga la petición este la intenta ejecutar al inicio y me da un error.
En fin muchas gracias por tu ayuda y me recomiendas que postee otra pregunta o aquí haga un inciso a forma de respuesta(pregunta)?

Comment: Me alegra que hayas podido resolver, la realidad es que son 2 preguntas diferentes a mi entender, entonces creo que quizás estaría bueno que queden separadas, porque otros podrían buscar específicamente en algún momento como enviar información de uno a otro, y eso ya está resuelto, por otro lado está el como accionar eso, es otro caso que también podría estar bueno que lo encuentren por separado, recuerda que nuestras preguntas/respuestas ayudan a otros también a la larga. Estoy a las órdenes.